# Why am I getting the error: 'ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 1)) while a minimum of 1 is required' when running my code?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I found a sample code on scikit-learn for running  a simple regression model. I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
import pandas as pd

#Define the path for the file
path=r"C:\Users\H\Desktop\Files\Sampledata.xlsx"

#Read the file into a dataframe ensuring to group by weeks
df=pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name = 0)
df=df.groupby(['Week']).sum()
df = df.reset_index()

#Define x and y
X=df[['Week']]
y=df['Payment Amount Total']

# Split the data into training/testing sets
X_train = X[:-20]
X_test = X[-20:]

# Split the targets into training/testing sets
y_train = y[:-20]
y_test = y[-20:]

# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Make predictions using the testing set
y_pred = regr.predict(X_test)

# The coefficients
print("Coefficients: \n", regr.coef_)
# The mean squared error
print("Mean squared error: %.2f" % mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
# The coefficient of determination: 1 is perfect prediction
print("Coefficient of determination: %.2f" % r2_score(y_test, y_pred))

# Plot outputs
plt.scatter(X_test, y_test, color="black")
plt.plot(X_test, y_pred, color="blue", linewidth=3)

plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

Everything is okay until I get to the following line:

```
regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

When I run this line I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 1)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
```

I'm not sure why I am getting this error.

This is what I get when I try to print the dataframes:

```
print(y_train)
print(y_test)
print(X_train)
print(X_test)
0      86546.38
1      83756.20
2      84961.71
3      70918.25
4      88554.72
5      90256.68
6      87202.41
7      75824.41
8      89538.01
9      88480.46
10     94556.43
11     91835.87
12     93248.96
13     94887.17
14     98587.10
15     96398.35
16     94210.16
17    100156.39
18     97870.76
19    103892.86
Name: Payment Amount Total, dtype: float64
Series([], Name: Payment Amount Total, dtype: float64)
0      86546.38
1      83756.20
2      84961.71
3      70918.25
4      88554.72
5      90256.68
6      87202.41
7      75824.41
8      89538.01
9      88480.46
10     94556.43
11     91835.87
12     93248.96
13     94887.17
14     98587.10
15     96398.35
16     94210.16
17    100156.39
18     97870.76
19    103892.86
Name: Payment Amount Total, dtype: float64
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Week]
Index: []


       Week
    0      3
    1      4
    2      5
    3      6
    4      7
    5      8
    6      9
    7     10
    8     11
    9     12
    10    13
    11    14
    12    15
    13    16
    14    17
    15    18
    16    19
    17    20
    18    21
    19    22
```

It should be noted that X actually prints values:

```
 Week
0      3
1      4
2      5
3      6
4      7
5      8
6      9
7     10
8     11
9     12
10    13
11    14
12    15
13    16
14    17
15    18
16    19
17    20
18    21
19    22
```

Comment: how does `X_train` and `y_train` look before you pass it to the `.fit()` function? do they contain data? Looks like at least one of them isn't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My train/test model is returning an error and is train/test model and normal linear regression model two separate models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73761979/my-train-test-model-is-returning-an-error-and-is-train-test-model-and-normal-lin)

Comment: I've added the results I get when I print the dataframes, one of them says 'empty' so @Damiaan you made a good suggestion.

Comment: The error is because one of them is empty

Comment: If you will use the sklearn split function - which splits by % - you won't get an empty set

Comment: Okay let me give it a go. I will let you know. What caused it to be empty? because when I print the X dataframe it returns values but as soon as I apply the split it becomes empty.

Comment: I had found the example here : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html so I figured it was the latest method.

Comment: You have the code I wrote in my answer below. Try it

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by doing the following before deploying the train/test method:

#features should be converted into a numpy array

```
X=df['Week'].values
```

#It should then be reshaped

```
X=X.reshape(-1,1)
```